SCSS error while passing numeric value as arguments
I have the following mixen, inside of it i'm trying to loop based on arguments.
@mixin detCls($s, $e) {
   @for $i from #{$s} through #{$e} {
    // doing some stuffs
    }
  }

@include detCls(16, 24)

But while complying it throws an error

@for $i from #{$s} through #{$e} { 16 is not a number.


You don't need string interpolation #{...}, just use $s , $e.
@mixin detCls($s, $e) {
   @for $i from $s through $e {
    // doing some stuffs
    }
 }

@include detCls(16, 24)


Interpolation with #{} is used for converting variables into strings, but in this case, you need the numeric values directly for the loop.
@mixin detCls($s, $e) {
   @for $i from $s through $e {
      // doing some stuff
   }
}

@include detCls(16, 24);



This is a copy of my answer

@DevScott we were writing at the same time. I did not copy from you.

I think you should guard input first by adding condition @if $s > $e then modify your forloop with this @for $i from $s through $e
